# Interaction term between independent variable and lagged dependent variable in xtabond

Tags: stata, interaction, panel-data

I am setting up a dynamic model in Stata 13 by using the `xtabond` command. I need to add interaction between the lagged dependent variable and other variables, as attached here [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4M6b.png)

My attempts:

```
 xtabond depvariable c.L1.depvariable#c.indvariable, lags(1) artests(2)
 xtabond depvariable c.L1.depvariable*c.indvariable, lags(1) artests(2)
 xtabond depvariable L1.depvariable*indvariable, lags(1) artests(2)
```

but they do not work.

Can someone please help me with the syntax? Or does some dirty alternative exist (for instance, creating interaction variable by hand)?

Comment: I forgot to mention: my variables are all continuous numerical!

Comment: You also forgot to mention *how* your attempts do not work: what happened when you tried them?

Comment: I note from Remark 12 in the output of `help tsvarlist` that the syntax in your first two examples may be incorrect. The remark suggests that in combining factor variables and time series operators, you would write either `cL.depvariable` or `Lc.depvariable`.

Comment: Also, this same question was raised on Statalist at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1330573-interaction-term-between-independent-variable-and-lagged-dependent-variable-in-xtabond